# staggering iterations over setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, iteration, easeljs

I'm trying to stagger for loops over time to draw a grid and keep system load down. For example: for a 100x100 grid that would be 10,000 iterations, instead of doing them all instantly, I want to do 1,000 then wait 250ms and carry on the next 1,000 until it's complete.

I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

In this example i am trying to do just that, but it only draws the first 1,000 squares, but  `console.log('iterate');` still runs and the iteration values follow on!

http://jsfiddle.net/FMJXB/2/

In this example, i have removed the `setTimeout` and instead calling the function twice, to simulate 2 loops with instant effect, and that draws 2,000 squares!

http://jsfiddle.net/FMJXB/3/

Why does having the function in a `setTimeout` stop the code from working?

Comment: Have you tried setInterval?

Comment: setInterval will try and run the code at precisely every 250ms whether the previous code has fully exected or not, which would not help spread the load. having a setTimeout at the end of each function, ensures the code has ran, and gives it a little breathing time.

Comment: I get what you mean.  It baffles me as much as it does you, I don't see why the timeout isn't firing properly.

Comment: It's weird because it does fire, and the iteration variable do increment as expected! `iterate 0 0,iterate 9 99,iterate 19 98,iterate 29 97,iterate 39 96,iterate 49 95,iterate 59 94,iterate 69 93,iterate 79 92,iterate 89 91,iterate 99 90` the log fires at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here’s a coding pattern to stagger drawing iterations using setTimeout**

The logic goes like this:

- Use variable ”j” to track horizontally draws across your grid.
- Use variable “i” to track vertical draws down your grid.
- Use variable “iterations” to cut the drawing into blocks of 1000 draws at a time
- When iterations has finished it’s 1000 draws, call setTimeout.

This code is for illustration—you will need to adapt it for your easelJS specific needs.

```
function draw(){

    // reset iterations for this block of 1000 draws
    var iterations = 0;

    // loop through 1000 iterations
    while(iterations++<1000){

        // put drawing code here
        graphics.drawRect(pixl.pixelSize*j, pixl.pixelSize*i, pixl.pixelSize, pixl.pixelSize);

        // increment i and j
        if(++j>canvas.width-1){ i++; j=0; }

        // if done, break
        if(i*j>pixelCount) { break; }

    }

    // schedule another loop unless we've drawn all pixels
    if(i*j<=pixelCount) {
        setTimeout(function(){ draw();  }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Z3fYG/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var i=0;
        var j=0;
        var pixelCount=canvas.width*canvas.height;

        draw();

        function draw(){

            ctx.beginPath();
            var iterations = 0;
            while(iterations++<1000){

                // put drawing code here
                ctx.rect(j,i,1,1);

                // increment i and j
                if(++j>canvas.width-1){ i++; j=0; }

                // if done, break
                if(i*j>pixelCount) { break; }

            }
            ctx.fill();

            // schedule another loop unless we've drawn all pixels
            if(i*j<=pixelCount) {
              setTimeout(function(){ draw();    }, 1000);
            }

        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas width="100" height="100" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! I'll have a look at implimenting this tonight, then i'll accept the answer. Any idea why the code in my example sems to fail on setTimeout but not when called directly though?